# Is it possible get a value from a string and to get the data type?

Tags: c#

Example:

```
var myvar = "123";
```

The current data type is a string, is it possible to get a number from the string and to get the data type?
Example return type of int.

Comment: The best that you can do is to see if the string is parseable to an int (i.e. via `int.TryParse`)

Comment: Your example is valid int, long, double, byte, short, and decimal values. Which one do you pick?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use .GetType() to get the data type and use TryParse to try to parse.

TryParse will work with most (if not all) data types. If you have an invalid datatype, then it should output the default datatype (o.o, o, "", etc...)

## Examples

(ran in Unity - just change print to console.writeLine or whatever method that you use to print to the console)

```
    var a = "123";
    print(a.GetType());
    // --> out: System.String
    int.TryParse(a, out var b);
    print(b);
    // --> out: 123
    print(b.GetType());
    // --> out: System.Int32
    int.TryParse("abc", out var c);
    print(c);
    // --> out: 0
    print(c.GetType());
    // --> out: System.Int32
```

Comment: Thanks, I need this, for another type unknown I need parse all types to take a correct type? To work with object is the equal?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question but if I understand it properly, you can use if, elseif, else ...for some reason switch case doesn't work. 
        Type typeA = "string".GetType();
        if (typeA == typeof(string))
        {
            //string
        }
        else if(typeA == typeof(int))
        {
            //int
        }else
        {
            //untracked type
        }